# I created one react project and I started working on Routing, Routing is working fine but Navbar is not working properly

Tags: reactjs

[! [My Output is shown like this. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUe61.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUe61.png).  I created one react project, and for designing I am using Bootstrap framework. I am done routing in my project. Routing is working fine, But Navbar is not working properly in my react project. So help me to resolve this issue.

This is App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';
import Edit from './Pages/Edit/Edit';
import Create from './Pages/Create/Create';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <div className="container">
        <h2>MERN</h2>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path='/id:/edit' component={Edit}></Route>
        <Route path='/create' component={Create}></Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In Components Folder, I have Navbar folder, I Navbar folder I have Navbar.js

In Navbar.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Navbar.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="www.facebook.com">
            Navbar
          </a>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item active">
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/id:/edit">Edit</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In Pages Folder I have three folders 1)Home 2)Create 3)Edit

This is Home.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Home.css";

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome to Home Component</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is Create.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Create extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome to Create Component</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is Edit.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Edit extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome to Edit Component</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my react project Routing is working fine, but Navbar is not working properly. If I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment.

Comment: make change  to <Navbar/>

Comment: Hi Kishan Jaiswal, I tried your idea but there is no change.

Comment: is there any error related to navbar

Comment: add <Navbar/> inside <div className="container">

Comment: No, there is no error, everything is working fine, but in Output Home, Craete, Edit are side by side like this--> HomeCreateEdit.

Comment: Now I added <Navbar/> in container but there is no change.

Comment: Did you imported bootstrap css correctly?  Show where you did this.

Comment: I Imported Bootstrap in Index.js file

Comment: Hi SuleymanSah, This is My Index.js I Imported Bootstrap css here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you just forgot to add the necessary `className` to your Links.
Add `className="nav-link"`  to Links in Navbar.js.

```
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
      <li className="nav-item active">
        <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
          Home
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">
          Create
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link to="/id:/edit" className="nav-link">
          Edit
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `Switch` component around all of your `<Route>` components?

You can find a similar example to what you are trying to achieve [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) in the first basic example.

Try:

```
<Router>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <div className="container">
        <h2>MERN</h2>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path='/id:/edit' component={Edit}></Route>
            <Route path='/create' component={Create}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Hi kcygan, Now I added Switch but there is no change.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a screenshot or a more in-depth description of the problem?

Comment: @Vamsi did you make sure to import the `Switch` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: Yes I Imported that.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by not-working properly, the "active" class is not changing.

For this you can use `"NavLink"` instead of `"Link"` from the react-router-dom package and do not hardcode the "active" class to the `<li>`

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
...
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to='/' activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to='/create' activeClassName="active">Create</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to='/id:/edit' activeClassName="active">Edit</NavLink>
                            </li>
...
```

Comment: Hi Dhananjai Pai, I tried your idea but there is no change.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing @Vamsi? Include the actual error/issue that you are trying to solve

Comment: I don't have any errors, but in the View the Output is coming like this  HomeCreateEdit .